# Spring Data MongoDB - Aggregation Framework - invalid reference in group Operation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I use Spring Data (1.3.0.RC1) to access our MongoDB and for some new queries I want to use the aggregation framework.

In the mongo shell the command would be:

```
db.spotreports.aggregate(
 { "$unwind" : "$pd"} , { "$group" : { "_id" : "$pd.PDch", "base" : {$sum : "$pd.aBL"}, "uplift" : {$sum : "$pd.up"}}})
{
"result" : [
{
"_id" : 5,
"base" : 529133,
"uplift" : 21516
},
...
```

The Spring Code I use is:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
Aggregation.unwind("pd"),
Aggregation.group("pd.PDch").sum("pd.aBL").as("base").sum("pd.up").as("uplift")
);

AggregationResults<SpotReportResult> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, resolveCollection(), SpotReportResult.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'PDch'!
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:63)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:47)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:284)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:228)
```

I wonder why spring want to reference 'PDch' instead of 'pd.PDch'?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Any chance you can file an issue and provide a minimal test case (i.e. domain class and aggregation definition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DATAMONGO-753](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-753) This should be fixed in the latest snapshots and released with the upcoming 1.3.2 bugfix release and the upcoming 1.4 M1 of Spring Data MongoDB.

Comment: broken in 1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: Faisal: if so, would you mind creating a ticket for that if you see it broken? Potentially with a test case attached?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `PDch` or `pd.PDch`.  For some reason the code is not using the `Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT` to get the field reference.  This is happens when ever there is more than one field.  Code works correctly if you only have one group field.