# mongodb Java Driver - $group with multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

My goal is to create a pipeline using the aggregation framework to group my data and then use this pipeline with the java driver. 
MongoDB v4.0.3

I created the following pipeline using MongoDB Compass (reduced to the important part):

```js
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: '$year',
            month: '$month',
            day: '$day',
            prodName: '$prodName',
            actionName: '$actionName'
        },
        actionCount: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
  }
]
```

This resulted in the following (generated) Java code:

```java
collectionName.aggregate(
  Arrays.asList(
    group(and(eq("year", "$year"),
              eq("month", "$month"),
              eq("day", "$day"),
              eq("prodName", "$prodName"),
              eq("actionName", "$actionName")),
         sum("actionCount", 1))
);
```

The data before the `$group` stage in the collection looks like this:

```js
{
 year: 2020,
 month: 01,
 day: 01,
 prodName: "productXY",
 actionName: "actionXY"
}
```

The `$group` stage should return the following data structure:

```js
{
  _id: {
    year: 2020,
    month: 01,
    day: 01,
    prodName: "productXY",
    actionName: "actionXY"
  },
  actionCount: 50
}
```

**The Problem**

Mongo Compass previews the result of the stage as expected, but the results of the stage using the java driver are very different. 
It only returns 1 Document (instead of 20 expected) and only returns the field `actionCount`.

**The Question**

How do I have to change the java code to create the desired pipeline stage?

Comment: The Compass generated Java code for aggregation's _group_ stage looks correct - there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. 
I needed to change the `and` operator to a `Projections.fields` operator. 
I still don't know why. Maybe someon else can elaborate about that.

So the working query looks like this:

```java
collectionName.aggregate(
  Arrays.asList(
    group(fields(eq("year", "$year"),
                 eq("month", "$month"),
                 eq("day", "$day"),
                 eq("prodName", "$prodName"),
                 eq("actionName", "$actionName")),
         sum("actionCount", 1))
);
```